# Avoiding Select * in cfc where ORM is not an option

Tags: coldfusion, cfc

In my CFCs, I have lists of DB fields that will be used in the SELECT statement inside of a cfquery

```
<cfcomponent>

<cfscript>
...

variables.lstNode = "NodeID,ParentNodeID,Root,Kind
  ,extra,Slug,title,subtitle,description,isbn,parenttitle,ParentCreateDate
  ,strData,xmlData,pinned,pStatus,cStatus
 ...
```

later in many many place I do things like

```
    <cfquery name="qryData">
        SELECT  #variables.lstNode# 
        FROM    dbo.vwNode WITH (NOLOCK)
```

What other approaches are there to this concern. Note ORM is not an option

Comment: And what exactly are the problems you are having with this system? Alternative approach could involve abstracting whole query as the standalone method/function where query options passed through arguments. This way it could be easier to manage later.

Comment: What exactly are you concerned about?

Comment: You could use a view or stored proc.

Comment: @DanBracuk I am concerned that his may be sloppy approach and that there is a better way to do it

Comment: At worst it's a constant variable in which case it would be more efficient to simply have the fields in your cfquery tag.

Comment: I should have pointed out in my original question, I do a select off of these fields in many different different places within the cfc

Comment: is it the same query in several places?  if so i'd put your query in a method inside your cfc and just pass in your where clause like sergii suggested.

Comment: They are all different queries. Only the select part is the same

Comment: so what might change?  where clause? filter by ISBN or title? order by maybe?  is it a single table or huge join?  If it's a join will the join change?

Comment: Yes sorting changes, filtering changes. The vwNode has 10s of thousands of rows if it were not filtered. 99% of the time it is filtered. Sometimes it is joined, sot he #variables.lstNode# is only a part of the select

Comment: Having read all the comments so far, I think you are taking a proper approach.  In fact, I do similar things myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have historically used cfproperty at the top of a CFC to define the database columns, and that just happens to be the way that ORM does it too. It is tidy, and it has the advantage that you could specify other attributes such as the datatype. If you plan to write standard methods for searching and editing your records, then it could be a good approach. Otherwise, it's probably needlessly complicated.